# Append to closest div class (multiple divs with same class on page)

Tags: jquery, append, closest

I'm trying to append content into the closest div class with name `".infoCatcher"`, but as of now it is appending to all divs with that class on the page.

How do I append this to the closest div?

I have this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnMoreInfo', function () {
    $('.item').closest('div').find('.infoCatcher').append('<div class="moreInfo info">' + '</div>');
});
```

And HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
        <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
        <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
        <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
        <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button class='btnMoreInfo'>More</button>
        <div class='infoCatcher'></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thankful for help!

Answer (score 4):

Try [`.siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/). Converted your code to fiddle. [Working version](http://jsfiddle.net/5ow1j3ok/) [is here](http://jsfiddle.net/shubh0602/kT3Rb/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(document).on('click', '.btnMoreInfo', function (e) {
       alert('Yes');
       $(e.target).siblings(".infoCatcher").append('<div class="moreInfo info">More Content..' + '</div>');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnMoreInfo', function () {
    $(this).closest('.infoCatcher').append('<div class="moreInfo info"></div>');
});
```

$(this) refers to the clicked btnMoreInfo